# Spring local and system properties

Tags: java, spring, properties

It is possible use local properties(declared in applicationContext.xml) in spring only if system properties(from operation system) not set. Now local properties overrided all system properties. I want that priority of system properties will be more that local.

I import local properties from file and system properties set in operation system:

`<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:localhost.properties" />`

I can't implement a custom PropertyPlaceholders.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to separate them into two and use order

```
<context:property-placeholder
  location="classpath*:*.properties"
  ignore-resource-not-found="true"
  ignore-unresolvable="true"
  order ="0" />

<context:property-placeholder
  location="file:/var/myfolder/local.properties"
  ignore-resource-not-found="true"
  ignore-unresolvable="true"
  order="-1"/>
```

lowest order takes precedence

Comment: System properties set in operating system.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't this what you want (from `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` api)?

```
public void setSystemPropertiesMode(int systemPropertiesMode)

Set how to check system properties: as fallback, as override, or never. For example, will resolve ${user.dir} to the "user.dir" system property.
The default is "fallback": If not being able to resolve a placeholder with the specified properties, a system property will be tried. "override" will check for a system property first, before trying the specified properties. "never" will not check system properties at all.
```

You should add this

```
<property name="searchSystemEnvironment" value="true"/>
<property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE"/>
```

To your place-holder configurer

Answer (score 0):

So you dont place them in local if I got it right? 
**Update**
Also you can use system_properties_mode_override i blv in systemPropertiesMode element of it

Comment: I can't do it. It is real big legacy project. It hard to explain. Sorry.